# grep select line

Tags: linux, grep

I want to select recently 7 days' record from log file also contain "OK LOGIN"

```
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12461] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12460] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon     password "gxxglxxxxt@google.com"
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:14 2012 [pid 12462] [ftp] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "66.249.68.236",   "/pub/10.5524/100001_101000/100022/readme.txt", 451 bytes, 1.39Kbyte/sec
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:22 2012 [pid 12677] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:23 2012 [pid 12676] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon password "xxxxxbot@google.com"
```

i using this command, but it doesn't work and how to write if i want to date= [current date - 7 days]

```
 cat vsftp.log | grep 'OK LOGIN' |egrep "Sep [1-6]"
```

Comment: Voting to close here and move - not a programming question

Comment: @Adrian: the question might be of low quality: the title and the error description "doesn't work" are not very specific.  But the OP shows some effort (minimal example that breaks is provided).  The problem is practical and answerable. You can definitely program in `bash`. How do you get `[current date - 7 days]` regexs without programming? You can fix it for [the provided example](http://ideone.com/lzQBV) but it is not a general solution. Given the above info alone why the question should be closed as offtopic? I can understand that it might be removed due to its low quality if not edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could [use `sed` to select range of lines and generate the regex using `date`](http://ideone.com/MDj71):

```
#!/bin/bash

function md()
{
    date +'%b %e' --date "$@"
}

start=`md 'last week'`
end=`md 'now'`
grep 'OK LOGIN' | sed -n "/$start/,/$end/p"
```

There should be at least one login each day. The regex is permissive there could be false positives.

Answer (score 0):

A space is missing:

```
grep 'OK LOGIN' vsftp.log | egrep "Sep  [1-6]"
```

Comment: 7 days include `Aug 30`. `'current date'` won't be always `Sep 6`